# How to clone a bootable USB drive with multiple partitions on Mac?

Tags: macos, bootable-disk

I have a 128 GB USB flash drive with 4 bootable macOS partitions.

Is there any way to clone this USB drive and keep all partitions bootable?

I want to share this USB drive to my friends and don't want to do this manually with createinstallmedia command?

Comment: I disagree that cloning is the same as doing a sector-by-sector copy. With cloning the necessary UUIDs are changed after the copy is made. There is no mention of this in any of the answers given to the [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286858/is-there-a-fast-way-i-can-clone-a-partition-on-to-another-drive-using-a-sector-b). Also, if the target drive is not exactly the same size as the source, then using the `dd` command alone will not place the secondary GPT at the end of the target drive. You would need additional software to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I managed to do this by creating a new dmg file from the target usb and burn the dmg file to new USB drives.

Comment: By burn, do you mean you used the Disk Utility or `asr` command to restore to the new USB drives? Or, something else? If I reopened the question, would you be willing to post your answer?

Comment: The question is still closed and can't post the answer. I burned the dmg file to usb with a commercial app.

Comment: Let me try this again. Your question has the tag "macos". I am on the [list of users who can reopen questions taged "macos"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/tag-badges/macos?badgeClass=Gold). I do not wish to reopen your question unless you are willing to post an answer. So, I want to **first** post a comment saying you willing post an answer.

Comment: OK. I am willing to post the details if I was granted the permission. Thanks

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I managed completing the task after hours of researching.

Step 1: Open Disk Utility app and unmount all partitions from the source USB drive. If you don't do this, an error says the disk is busy and operation failed.

Step 2: From the ***File*** menu, ***New Image*** -> ***Image from "USB drive name"***.

[image]

Step 3: Choose a location to save the .dmg file on your Mac.

Step 4: Buy [UUByte DMG Editor](https://www.uubyte.com/dmg-editor.html) (paid software) and flash the .dmg file to new USB drive. The target USB drive should be equal or larger than the source drive.

Once the task is finished, the target drive will have the same partitions and all of them are bootable. Repeat the process if you want to clone more USB drives. At this time, you should only burn the dmg file to USB.

In short, make a disk image (.dmg) from the source USB drive and burn the dmg to new USB drives. That's!

[***Update***] Disk Utility's Restore feature does not work in this way. The test dmg is imaged from a 16GB flash drive with one macOS installer. The USBs are fully functional as they worked fine with DMG Editor. Here is the error screenshot from Disk Utility app:

[image]

Comment: I would think the Disk Utility's restore feature would provide the same functionality. Do you know if using the trial version of UUByte is sufficient, or would one need to purchase a license key to use the full version?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the Disk Utility restore feature at first but without any luck (three USB drives). It says "couldn't validate source - Invalid argument. The operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus error 22)". No, you need to buy a license to activate the software. It worths the money as it saves a lot of time and has a progress bar to monitor the whole process.

Comment: Did you do a "Scan Image for Restore..."?

Comment: Also come with an error: can't open "path/to/.dmg" read/write. Operation failed with status -1. For your reference, the .dmg file is created with read-only option.